# Ломается кодировка

Tags: html, visual-studio, кодировка, visual-studio-code

Сохраняю файл HTML в VS. Кириллица отображается корректно. После, если открыть программу в VS code, русские символы заменяются на воросительные знаки. Кодировка в vs code - utf 8.
После этого в VS символы так же отображаются не корректно. Побывал менять кодировку, но не помогло.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вставить в `head` это: 
`<meta charset="utf-8">`
Этот участок кода задаёт кодировку символов, используемую на странице.
[Статья на MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset)